# repair a damaged package that is blocked

Tags: package-management, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I've upgraded my Ubuntu (by means of `sudo do-release-upgrade`) to 18.04 LTS, but something went wrong. Now I'm able to login to Plasma only and not Ubuntu.

When I run Synaptic, it advices me that there are three damaged packages: `debconf`, `libpango1.0-0` and `ubuntu-desktop`.

When I try to reinstall them, I get the message: Impossible to apply the changes. You have to repair the packages before.

If I open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get -f install` I get the messages: `Impossible to set the block /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open` and `Impossible to get the block on the administration folder. Another process could take it busy`.

Which steps have I do follow to repair my system?

Comment: Did you close synaptic before attempting to run the terminal commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Comment: Due to the deadlock of my situation, I was forced to re-install the new ubuntu release.